# Spring Batch Integration -- Remote Chunking Slave Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

What's the standard configuration for ensuring that exceptions on the slave are mapped to a response on the master that will indicate that the remote step actually failed?

At the moment any exceptions that happen in the service activator on the slave just completely stop the flow, and I get no response on the master until the whole thing times out.  I can add a couple retries on the slave (using [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain) info from the manual) but if it just fails completely or is an exception I don't want to retry I need a failure response to be sent to the master immediately.

The docs on remote chunking are unfortunately pretty sparse and I can't find anything showing how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With partitioning, you should get a `StepExecution` back, regardless of success/failure:

```
@ServiceActivator
public StepExecution handle(StepExecutionRequest request) {

    Long jobExecutionId = request.getJobExecutionId();
    Long stepExecutionId = request.getStepExecutionId();
    StepExecution stepExecution = jobExplorer.getStepExecution(jobExecutionId, stepExecutionId);
    if (stepExecution == null) {
        throw new NoSuchStepException("No StepExecution could be located for this request: " + request);
    }

    String stepName = request.getStepName();
    Step step = stepLocator.getStep(stepName);
    if (step == null) {
        throw new NoSuchStepException(String.format("No Step with name [%s] could be located.", stepName));
    }

    try {
        step.execute(stepExecution);
    }
    catch (JobInterruptedException e) {
        stepExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.STOPPED);
        // The receiver should update the stepExecution in repository
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        stepExecution.addFailureException(e);
        stepExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED);
        // The receiver should update the stepExecution in repository
    }

    return stepExecution;

}
```

(`StepExecutionRequestHandler`).

With chunking you should get a `ChunkResponse` either way...

```
@ServiceActivator
public ChunkResponse handleChunk(ChunkRequest<S> chunkRequest) throws Exception {

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Handling chunk: " + chunkRequest);
    }

    StepContribution stepContribution = chunkRequest.getStepContribution();

    Throwable failure = process(chunkRequest, stepContribution);
    if (failure != null) {
        logger.debug("Failed chunk", failure);
        return new ChunkResponse(false, chunkRequest.getSequence(), chunkRequest.getJobId(), stepContribution, failure.getClass().getName()
                + ": " + failure.getMessage());
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Completed chunk handling with " + stepContribution);
    }
    return new ChunkResponse(true, chunkRequest.getSequence(), chunkRequest.getJobId(), stepContribution);

}
```

(`ChunkProcessorChunkHandler`)

Comment: That was for partitioning; I added a comment about chunking.

Comment: Ok.  I had configured a `FaultTolerantChunkProcessor` instead of a `SimpleChunkProcessor` (before I dropped down to a chunk size of 1) and handling of that in `ChunkProcessorChunkHandler.process` seems to cause the exception not to propagate.  I think I'm good now.  Thanks for the help.